# rails 3.2 skip paperclip attachment presence validation on edit action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am new to Rails and i'm working on my first rails application that uses paperclip for attachments and i'm validating the presence of attachment using `validates_attachment :avatar, presence: true` which is working perfectly well on create action, but when a user is editing his account settings and doesn't upload a new avatar, there is  an error for not having avatar uploaded but i want to skip that validation on edit and only validate on edit if user uploads a new one to replace existing one.
i also have

`validates_format_of :avatar, :with => %r{\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$}i,:unless => Proc.new {|m| m[:avatar].nil?}, :message => "Please upload files with the following extensions only`

to check format only if present but doesn't seem to be working either
your help would be very much appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use on option.

```
validates_format_of :avatar ... , :on => :create
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/activerecord_validations_callbacks.html#on

Comment: Attachment is polymorphic nested, in my case - on the Attachment model: validates :file, :presence => true, :on => :create, :file_size => { :maximum => 20.megabytes.to_i } .  On edit, it still wraps the error when there is no file.  Also, no validation for presence on the parent model.  Now using custom JS to remove the errror-class broken-magic when on controller-method-edit, but would welcome a way to actually fix it.