# Paperclip validations are not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Paperclip is allowing any kind of file upload, and I don't understand. In my app, by default, Users don't have to upload avatars when they register, but they may update their avatar after registration. And the user is able to successfully update their avatar. This all works fine, but the validations are not kicking in.

Validation code below in the User.rb:

```
has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :profile => "150x150#"}, :default_url => 'missing_:style.png'

validates_attachment :avatar, presence: true,
          content_type: { content_type: ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png'], :message => 'must be a PNG, JPG, or JPEG'},
          size: {less_than: 5.megabytes, :message => 'must be less than 5 megabytes'}
```

In my routes I have this:

```
put 'updateavatar' => 'profile#updateavatar'
```

This is my form:

```
<%= form_for current_user, :html => { :multipart => true }, :url => {:action => 'updateavatar'} do |form| %>
  <%= form.file_field :avatar %>
  <%= form.submit "Upload", class: "btn uploadbtn" %>
<% end %>
```

I don't know why this wouldn't work? It's literally allowing any kind of file to be uploaded when the user updates their profile.

In my profile controller I have this:

```
  def updateavatar
   if params[:user][:password].blank?
     params[:user].delete(:password)
     params[:user].delete(:password_confirmation)
   end
   respond_to do |format|
     if current_user.update_attribute(:avatar, params[:user][:avatar])
       flash[:notice] = 'successfully updated.'
       format.html { redirect_to profile_index_path }
     else
       format.html { render action: "index" }
     end
   end
 end
```

Comment: Try using validates_attachment_content_type as a separate validation.

Comment: unfortunately, validations are still skipping.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12686796/1251349

Comment: my thought is you have to use `update_attribute` with a ! sign, `current_user.update_attribute!(:avatar, params[:user][:avatar])` this will raise an error and also should brake your logic chain at `if current_user.update_attribute...` not really sure you need this exactly.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I saw that post earlier, but unfortunately, it didn't solve my issue. @rmagnum2002, I get a undefined method `update_attribute!' for #<User:0x000001039c2f30> with that code.

Comment: I fixed it. current_user.update_attributes(:avatar => params[:user][:avatar]) worked. update_attribute skips validations it seems. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**update_attribute**

```
  # File vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb, line 2614
2614:       def update_attribute(name, value)
2615:         send(name.to_s + '=', value)
2616:         save(false)
2617:       end
```

**update_attributes**

```
  # File vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb, line 2621
2621:       def update_attributes(attributes)
2622:         self.attributes = attributes
2623:         save
2624:       end
```

so, using `update_attribute` will update the object but will skip the validations, using `update_attributes` will update object with validations.

looks like in controller you should have:

```
if current_user.update_attributes(:avatar, params[:user][:avatar]) .....
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured that out.

Comment: Thanks, please be careful when using `update_attribute` since that skips validations.

Answer (score 0):

current_user.update_attributes(:avatar => params[:user][:avatar]) fixed it